# How to register BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new to android.I tried to register Broadcastreceiver in main class to receive sms.But when i m running logcat shows "error in receiving broadcast intent" and the application become force close.Whats the solution for this?
Here is my code:

```
 public class Yes extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private Retrieve receiver = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button start=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt1);
start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            receiver = new Retrieve();
                registerReceiver(receiver,new
                            IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));

             }
           });
              }
             private class Retrieve extends BroadcastReceiver
               {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
    for (int n = 0; n<messages.length; n++) {
    smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
     smsMessage[0].getMessageBody();

    }

     // show first message
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
    "Received SMS: " + smsMessage[0].getMessageBody(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
           }}
```

I put a start button and i tried to rgister receiver within that button.I provide permission in manifest file to receive sms.i didn't write intent filter in manifest.I think the way i register receiver is completely wrong from what i want to do.help me...

Answer (score 0):

In your activity outside, create a broadcast(or write it as a seperate Class):

```
private BroadcastReceiver smsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //do your task
    }
}
```

In onClick just regist the Receiver:

```
registerReceiver(smsReceiver, filter);
```

Comment: Thanks John, Is semicollan is needed after your code? Now my error said Are u missing a call to unregister receiver? How can i unregister if i register it inside button. Toast message also doesn't appear.only notification bar is seen.what to do?

Comment: problem solved after i register receiver in manifest file and wrote code for broadcastreceiver in a seperate class.

Comment: call unRegisterReceiver(smsReceiver); when you don't need it any more...For Example, in the Activity's onStop() mehtod. If register in manifest I think the Android will manage it automatically

Comment: If we register receiver in manifest,it leaked the intent receiver to other application..The solution for this is to uninstall other application before running our application.But it can be solved significantly via register and unregister in main activity itself.